# Many to Many relationships with an initial pivot condition

Tags: mysql

I have three tables `groups`, `users` and `group_user`.
While `groups` and `users` have an `id` and `name` column, the bellow is
the `group_user` table

```html
+----+----------+---------+
| id | group_id | user_id |
+----+----------+---------+
| 12 | 5        | 1       |
| 13 | 5        | 8       |
| 14 | 5        | 7       |
+----+----------+---------+
```

The issue am facing is, I have a user with id `7`, and am trying
to get the group of this user (which is `5` from above schema diagram), then retrieve every other user
in that group (user with id `1` and `8`).

I tried doing something like this:

```sql
select `groups`.id, `groups`.name, users.id, users.name from `groups`
left join group_user on `groups`.id = group_user.group_id and group_user.user_id = 7
left join users on group_user.user_id = users.id
```

And expectedly the result is not accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following query:

```
select g.name group_name, u.name user_name from group_user gu
left join users u on u.id = gu.user_id
left join groups g on g.id = gu.group_id
where gu.group_id in (select group_id from group_user where user_id = 7)
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my question to be less confusing, I dont need the ids only, i need the records in both the users, groups table.

Comment: please check my updated query, i tested with groups and users tables that are including id and name fields. you can add more required fields to group and user.

Answer (score 1):

You must join `users` to 2 copies of `group_user` and finally `groups` with `INNER` joins:

```
select gu2.group_id, g.name group_name, u.id user_id, u.name user_name 
from `users` u
inner join group_user gu on gu.user_id = u.id 
inner join group_user gu2 on gu2.group_id = gu.group_id and gu2.user_id = 7
inner join `groups` g on g.id = gu2.group_id
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/NoXU7rZTCtjBsCmag23Ps/4).